# How a uniform distribution may induce different solution regarding Bertrand's paradox

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a neophyte question regarding the formulation of the Bertrand's paradox.
This is related to the definition of what we call a uniform distribution.
If we consider the 3 point of views of “random endpoints” method, “random radius” method and “random midpoint” method, is the randomness (supposed to be uniform in each case) equivalent between the three methods?
Indeed a simple case considering a random variable X to be uniform. The new variable Y defined as Y=X^2 is not uniformly distributed because it is the argument X which is uniform.

My question is: are the three methods equivalent in term of randomness ? The uniform distribution in 1st method may induce perhaps a bias in the equivalent randomness in the 2 other methods. I don't know how to demonstrate it mathematically.
If this is true, each method supposes the cord being uniformly distributed but indeed, they are not equivalent.
Should it be a a ill-problem ? because we need to define what we call "uniformly distributed" and w.r.t. what Space subset domain.
Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: Define the pdf in each case,  These would be equal.

Comment: Method Random endpoints: Pick two random points on the circumference of the circle. In this case the Space subset is the circumference of the circle.

Method Random radius: Pick a random radius of the circle and then a random point on the radius. Construct the unique chord perpendicular to the point. The subset is the area of the circle including the circumference. But 2 randomness.

Method Random midpoint: Pick a point inside the circle at random and take this to be the midpoint of the chord perpendicular to the radius containing it. The subset same as method 2 but 1 randomness.

Answer (score 1):

Jaynes gives a [fairly good treatment of the paradox](https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/well.pdf) with an approach based on his [principle of transformation groups](https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/groups.pdf).  I think you'll find his take satisfying, given the last few sentences of your question.

[This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.09072.pdf) skeptical reading/re-analysis of Jaynes' argument is also quite good.

Above all: if confusion threatens when trying to rigorously interpret statements of probability, always remember that [we don't have to](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10670-017-9936-9).